# Convertir DIV Html5 a Imagen o PDF C# /Jquery ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hola amigos como puedo convertir un div a una img en C#/ASP.Net ?

Quiero capturar mapas de Google desde una APP en C# ASP.Net

Lo intenté con Windows Forms CopyScreen peor ya publicado en IIS me dice COntrolador No Valido

Tienen alguna idea?

Answer (score 1):

```
Con esta libreria 

    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jspdf.min.js"></script>

ejemplo: 
tu div

    <div id="areaImprimir">
        tu contenido....
        </div>

la funcion: 

   <script type="text/javascript">
        function genPDF() {
            var pdf = new jsPDF('PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 100f, 0f');
            pdf.addHTML($('#areaImprimir'),
                5,
                5,
                function () {
                    pdf.save('div.pdf');
                });
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: especifica donde encontrar la librería y también el uso de la misma. No solo pongas el código.